# What is the process of coffee acting as a taste blocker in conjunction with menthol/mint

Tags: flavor, chemistry

Background, I vape a mint (spearmint and peppermint) with menthol. When I drink any kind of coffee and for some time after, the vape has a different (not so nice) taste. It can be black coffee, something fancy from a coffee shop, or anything else.

This got me wondering, what is the chemical process that is going on here. Is there something about coffee that binds to some taste receptors? If so which ones.

I am casually interested in the science of what is happening in my mouth when I drink coffee as evidenced by changes in flavours of something else.

Comment: Does this happen only when you drink coffee? What about other foods like yoghurt or just after brushing your teeth (with toothpaste)? If those also affect the taste of vaping, maybe it's more of a biology question? See also the [*taste* tag on Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taste).

Comment: I've only noticed it with coffee.

Comment: This [paper](https://doi.org/10.1093/chemse/28.1.45) might be useful. The TLDR from the paper is that the methol compound itself is considered to be bitter tasting.